# what does IsSecured property for TcpChannel do?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I have a client server application using .Net Remoting. We have TcpChannel object to establish the connection between client and server. So if I set the IsSecured property for TcpChannel object to true. Does this mean that the data passed between client and server is secure i.e. encrypted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `secure` flag to true, exchanged content is encrypted and signed.

You can observe that easily by using your favorite network sniffer (e.g. WireShark).